# Zxing weird image reverse

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android, zxing, xamarin

I am writing C# lib for very simple recognize image to use it in `monodroid` and also using `zxing` port to C#.  But after I read image bytes from file I do such thing, same as in `zxing` barcode scanning.

```
binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(rawRgb, width, height, format)));
```

But somehow it reverse image by vertical. I just saving `binaryBitmap` as bitmap to file by pixels.

Please help me understand why it's happen? What am I doing wrong?

@Michael am using Zxing.Net.Mobile port, from here https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile. It's very weird for me it I am using PlanarYUVLuminanceSource - then I get such image http://i.imgur.com/OlwqC0I.png, but if I am using RGBLuminanceSource then I get full almost normal image, see example image. so now I have even 2 questions:

1. why planar take only part of image and have "layer on layer" effect? and
2. ok if I will use RGBLuminanceSource then, why it have some invertion of colors, I mean somewhere rectangles border is black and somewhere they are white. because it real image they all black?

UPDATE:
Here is how I get bytes from device and also as you see I set nv21 format, so it must be YUV, no? I wonder, what I am doing wrong that rgb source work(at list image is ok) and PLanarYUV not :((
BTW, original byte from preview frame have result and same file size.
Any suggestion?

```
public void OnPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
{
var img = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormatType.Nv21, cameraParameters.PreviewSize.Width, cameraParameters.PreviewSize.Height, null); string _fileName2 = "YUV_BYtes_"+ DateTime.Now.Ticks +".txt";
    string pathToFile2 = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, _fileName2);
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile2, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        fileStream.Write(img.GetYuvData(), 0, img.GetYuvData().Length);
    }
}


    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, global::Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
    {
        if (camera == null)
            return;

        var parameters = camera.GetParameters();

        width = parameters.PreviewSize.Width;
        height = parameters.PreviewSize.Height;
        parameters.PreviewFormat = ImageFormatType.Nv21;
        //parameters.PreviewFrameRate = 15;


        //this.height = size.height;
        //this.width = size.width;
        //camera.setParameters( params );

        //parameters.PreviewFormat = ImageFormatType.;

        camera.SetParameters(parameters);
        camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.StartPreview();

        cameraResolution = new Size(parameters.PreviewSize.Width, parameters.PreviewSize.Height);

        AutoFocus();
    }
```

Comment: Which zxing port do you use? There are different ones out there. Please post the code which you use to save the binaryBitmap.

Comment: @Michael I have added answer to your question, to main question. Thanks!

Comment: really weird image. I can't image that this should be a problem of zxing.net. Other people should have the same experience in such a case. Did you try the latest source of ZXing.Net.Mobile from github? Can you give me the original image and/or a dump of the image rgb data?

Comment: @Michael I have upload file to google drive, please you can download it, save and read bytes from it. This image convertion make me srazy...    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B05QJExBv861RUNmV2p1N2llbWs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you have done. The data looks like RGB565 bitmap data (or something similar). You can't put such a byte array into the PlanarYUVLuminanceSource. You have to make sure that the byte array which you use with the planar source is really a array with only yuv data, not RGB565.
The rules are easy:
if you use the following code snippet

```
new RGBLuminanceSource(rawRgb, width, height, format)
```

make sure that the value of format matches the layout and data of the parameter rawRgb.
if you use somethin glike the following

```
new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(yuvBytes, 640, 960, 0, 0, 640, 960, false);
```

make sure that yuvBytes only contains real yuv data.
I can only give a better answer if you post a more complete code sample.

Comment: What is the width and the height of the preview image?

Comment: thanks for your help, but problem was in fu... device :( BUT camera work ok on it, weird. Because I have tried on another device and all ok.